# Criar DIV com borda cruzando o titulo

Tags: html, css

Estou precisando fazer uma div que tenha uma borda de 2 px, porem essa div tem um titulo e preciso que esse titulo fique centralizado com a borda.

Veja e imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso? pesquisei aqui no site mas não encontrei uma solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo como isso:

```css
.form1 {
  text-align: 'center'
}
.form1 fieldset{
  border: 2px solid #06c;
}
.form1 legend{
  text-align: 'center'
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="form1" action="/">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Formulário 1</legend>
    Nome:<br>
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" >
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Use a tag [fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)

> Definição e uso: A tag `<fieldset>` é usada para agrupar elementos
>   relacionados em um formulário.
>
> A tag `<fieldset>` desenha uma caixa em torno dos elementos
>   relacionados.
>
> Dica: A tag `<legend>` define uma legenda para o elemento `<fieldset>`.

Configurações **CSS** padrão: A maioria dos navegadores exibirá o elemento `<fieldset>` com os seguintes valores padrão. [Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)

```
fieldset { 
    display: block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-top: 0.35em;
    padding-bottom: 0.625em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
    border: 2px groove (internal value);
}
```

**Exemplo**

```css
legend {
  border: 2px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Dados Pessoais:</legend>
    Nome: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Nascimento: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer, usando `div`:

```css
.title_box {
  border: black 2px solid;
}

.title_box #title {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline;
  background-color: white;
}

.title_box #content {}
```

```html
<div class="title_box" id="subject">
  <div id="title">Filtro de disciplina</div>
  <div id="content">
    TEXT.<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Curiosidade: a pergunta pede por uma borda sólida de 2 px, por que fez uma borda de 1 px pontilhada?

Comment: Eu achei uma resposta que usava `div` e repliquei rapidamente, achei que seria um tanto "perfumaria" fazer a borda idêntica já que o problema maior tem relação com centralizar o texto na borda. Corrigi a resposta. Obrigado.